# JavaScript API that loads and houses libraries of code

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I have written a JavaScript API that loads and houses libraries of code to do all sorts of things on websites.

Effectively, this is (will be) the base JavaScript for all the websites I build.

The aim of this API is to load the required libraries (`SM.load()`) needed for a particular page, and add them to the library as a plugin (`SM.run()`).

You may be surprised as to how I have written this library, just to explain in brief. I have aliased the jQuery selector, so that if you run:

```
SM('#test').foo()
```

It will retrieve `#test` using the jQuery constructor function and then chain the result through to the `foo()` function. However, you can also run functions like this:

```
SM.bar()
```

Effectively this just mimics the way you can do this in jQuery:

```
$('#test').show()
$.ajax(options)
```

---

```
/**
 * Sine Macula Javascript API
 * The Sine Macula API contains all base functions for the Sine Macula
 * Javascript Library
 * @name class.sinemacula.js
 * @author Ben Carey
 * @version 1.0
 * @date 20/11/2012
 * @copyright (c) 2012 Sine Macula Limited (sinemaculammviii.com)
 */
(function(global, $){

    // Enable strict mode
    "use strict";

    // Set the global variables for Sine Macula
    var oldSM, SM;

    // Make sure jQuery has loaded
    if(typeof $ !== "function"){
        throw "jQuery must be loaded";
    }

    /**
     * Sine Macula Object
     * The main Sine Macula library
     *
     * @param string The element to be selected
     */
    SM = global.SM = global.SineMacula = SineMacula;
    function SineMacula(selector){
        // Construct and return an instance of the
        // Sine Macula object
        return new _initialize(selector);
    }

    /**
     * Sine Macula Constructor
     * Alias of the jQuery Selector
     *
     * @param string The element to be selected
     */
    function _initialize(selector){
        // Retrieve the elements matching the selector
        // and make it available to all the Sine Macula
        // methods
        this.elements = $(selector);
    }

    // So that plugins can add to _initialize.prototype, make it available
    // as a property of SineMacula: SineMacula.fn (aka SM.fn)
    SM.fn = _initialize.prototype;

    /**
     * Sine Macula Run
     * Makes it easy to write plugins for the Sine Macula library
     *
     * @param function callback
     */
    SM.run = run;
    function run(callback){
        // Call the function with the Sine Macula
        // and jQuery objects
        callback(SM, $);
    }

    /**
     * Sine Macula Load
     * Load the Sine Macula Libraries and Plugins
     * into the current document
     *
     * The options:
     * - package: the package of libraries to load
     * - packageURL: a remote source to load the package details from
     * - libraries: any additional libraries to load
     *
     * @param object options The options for the Sine Macula load
     */
    SM.load = load;
    function load(options){     
        var url,query,script;       
        // Set the defaults for the loader
        var options = $.extend({
            package:    'none', // Do not load any packages by default
            packageURL: false, // Do not retrieve the package details from a URL by default
            libraries:  [] // Do not load any libraries by default
        },options);     
        // Build the query based on the parameters supplied
        if(options.packageURL){         
            // Build the query to allow for a remote
            // package definition
            query = '?packageURL='+encodeURIComponent(options.packageURL);
        }else if(options.package=='none'){          
            // If no package has been supplied then just
            // provide libraries to load
            query = '?libraries='+encodeURIComponent(options.libraries.join());
        }else{          
            // If a package has been supplied then
            // request it, and any additional libraries
            query = encodeURIComponent(options.package)+'/?libraries='+encodeURIComponent(options.libraries.join());
        }       
        // Complete the url by appending the query
        url = '//libraries.sinemaculammviii.com/'+query;        
        // Append the script tag to the end of the document
        script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = url;
        $('head')[0].appendChild(script);       
    }

    /**
     * IndexOf
     * A fix to allow the call of the indexOf function
     * in Internet Explorer
     */
    if(!Array.prototype.indexOf){
        Array.prototype.indexOf = function (searchElement /*, fromIndex */ ) {
            "use strict";
            if (this == null) {
                throw new TypeError();
            }
            var t = Object(this);
            var len = t.length >>> 0;
            if (len === 0) {
                return -1;
            }
            var n = 0;
            if (arguments.length > 1) {
                n = Number(arguments[1]);
                if (n != n) { // shortcut for verifying if it's NaN
                    n = 0;
                } else if (n != 0 && n != Infinity && n != -Infinity) {
                    n = (n > 0 || -1) * Math.floor(Math.abs(n));
                }
            }
            if (n >= len) {
                return -1;
            }
            var k = n >= 0 ? n : Math.max(len - Math.abs(n), 0);
            for (; k < len; k++) {
                if (k in t && t[k] === searchElement) {
                    return k;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
    }
})(this, this.jQuery);
```

Comment: SM? [Really](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sadomasochism)?

Comment: [related](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=SM)

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Hahahaha, oh dear!! Didnt think of that!! It stands for Sine Macula. I may change that now!

Comment: @BenCarey And btw fix your `indexOf` shim. Right now, it shims all the time even when the method exists. See the [official shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility).

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Thank you very much, have amended my script :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a once over:

- I like `use strict` in an IIFE
- However, the second `use strict` in `indexOf` is overkill
- You are not using the variable `oldSM`
- Lots of comments are good as well
- The below code is prepending really, and the hostname should be called out in separate variable or even better be derived from `window.location`

  ```
  // Complete the url by appending the query
  url = '//libraries.sinemaculammviii.com/'+query;
  ```
- From a design perspective, I am not sure what you are providing with your script, except for a shell over jQuery. jQuery even has `jQuery.getScript()` which could replace

  ```
  // Append the script tag to the end of the document
  script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = url;
  $('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  ```

  it also has `jQuery.inArray` which you could use instead of your `indexOf` shim.